# \renewcommand to redefine \cite

Tags: citing

I would like to redefine `\cite{}` so that text like

```
\cite{blah:1991:pldi}
```

gets replaced by

```
\cite{blah:1991:pldi:short}
```

I tried the following:

```
\let\oldcite\cite
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{\oldcite}{#1:short}}
```

However, this does not work with multiple arguments to `\cite{}`.

For instance, I would like

```
\cite{blah1, blah2}
```

to be replaced by

```
\cite{blah1:short, blah2:short}
```

as well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Prakash, welcome to TeX.sx! I've formatted your code snippets, which you can also do yourself by selecting them and pressing the `{}` button (or pressing `Ctrl+k`. I've also removed the "Thanks" at the end of the question, which is common practice on this site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that you do not use packages that redefine `\cite` (like `cite.sty`), try this:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@citex[#1]#2{\leavevmode
  \let\@citea\@empty
  \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\ }%
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
     \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb:short}}\fi
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\hbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}%
       \G@refundefinedtrue
       \@latex@warning
         {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
       {\@cite@ofmt{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}}{#1}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: @Prakash: If you find the answer helpful, you should upvote it. If you feel your question is answered, you can and should mark it as such by clicking the tick mark next to the answer.

Comment: @Jake: Sure. Just did.